# How to enable SMTP for IIS 8?

Tags: windows-8, smtp, iis-8

I can't find where to enable the `SMTP` on `Windows 8 Pro`.
Surprisingly enough I didn't even find answers online.
Has anyone figured this out yet?

As usual I checked that all necessary `IIS` components were installed:

[image]

Still no SMTP configuration on `inetmgr`:

[image]

Comment: See official documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b83ac7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @user1929959 that's for IIS6, as I said I need it to work for IIS8. Thanks.

Comment: @user1929959 thank you. Before I asked this question I followed that link's instruction. You can even see that in my pictures, still it didn't work.

Comment: See http://pdhewaju.com.np/blog/how-to-install-smtp-on-windows-8-developer-preview/ and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6cde20/install-iis-8-on-windows-8/. Also, check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Windows 8 no longer allows SMTP Server, just merely SMTP Service. You can forward to a server with existing SMTP capabilities but no longer will it act as a server in IIS.

Reference:
http://www.neatcomponents.com/enable-SMTP-in-Windows-8

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked that link and did it exactly as said there. I got some other services added, still no SMTP. Did that work for you?

Comment: I had to use a Windows 2003 server for SMTP. You can also create a VM with Windows 7 or earlier and add SMTP capabilities to forward from host to guest.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an answer that may help a few people. I have just set up a development server on Windows 8.1 Pro that has a number of legacy classic ASP sites that I still need to support, and I really didn't want to change all the mail code.

Lots of answers across the web tell you to just install the IIS6 compatibility, however I believe this is for server OSes only - it does not work on Windows 8 Pro. The IIS6 snapin just says the SMTP Service is not installed when you try to connect.

CAVEAT: This is only useful for development; it allows you to continue using the CDO pickup code to put emails in a Pickup directory with no errors so you can see and debug the email you applications are sending, but it WILL NOT actually send anything.

1. Go to `Turn Windows features on or off`
2. Turn on `Internet Information Services\Web Management Tools\IIS 6 Management Compatibility \IIS Metabase and IIS6 configuration compatibility`
3. Download and install `IIS Resource Kit Tools`: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17275
4. Run `Metabase Explorer` as Administrator
5. Right click `LM`, add new Key `SmtpSvc`
6. Right click `LM\SmtpSvc`, add new Key `1`
7. Right click `LM\SmtpSvc\1`, add new String Record `PickupDirectory`, with the directory of your choice (I just created a `\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup` for familiarity's sake)
8. Create the folder you specified above, if not present
9. Add Modify access to `IIS_IUSRS` to the folder you just created
10. Restart IIS from the normal IIS manager

All of your legacy CDO pickup-using code should now drop emails in that directory. Here is simple test page to check:

```
<%@ language="JScript" %>
<%
        var mailer = Server.CreateObject('CDO.Message');

        mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 1; 
        mailer.Configuration.Fields.Update();

        mailer.From = 'rob@example.com';
        mailer.To = 'rob@example.com';
        mailer.Subject = 'Test';

        mailer.TextBody = 'Blah blah';

        mailer.Send();
%>
```

You will get an error about the pickup directory not being specified if the metabase setup hasn't worked, an access denied error if you haven't set permissions on the directory correctly, and nothing at all if it's worked.

Comment: Awesome, thank you past me! Future you is helped by this!

Comment: I really hope I don't have to do this, but really glad I found this post.

Answer (score 7):

I faced a similar issue in windows 2012. But there is a virtual SMTp Server available in windows 2012.

Procedure is 
1. I  installed IIS Manager . In 2012 I searched for IIS. it popped 2 searches one was for IIS6. I selected that one . Here you find that you can configure SMTP relay.

If you have doubts then write me and I will explain in detail.

Comment: Even easier than that.  If you use the Server Manager in server 2012 to "Add Roles and Features" and select SMTP, it will automatically also select the prerequisite IIS 6 Management Console tools and whatever else it needs.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but the problem is that the SMTP settings are hiding in the IIS 6 manager and not in IIS 8 manager where you would think they would be. In the Server Manager Dashboard, select the Tools menu, then launch the Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager.

Comment: The question is about Windows 8 not server OS.

Comment: true, but this is the correct and valid answer for 'how to enable smtp for iis 8' for people that just read the header